# What does "break-up of the body after death" mean in the suttas?

Tags: pali-canon

The Pali suttas, particularly in teachings about kamma, has the phrase: "*at the break-up of the body after death*".

Are there contexts other than kamma where this phrase is used?

What does "*break-up of the body after death*" actually mean in the suttas?

Are these words in the language of materialism?

Do they have a non-materialistic meaning?

Answer (score 6):

"break-up of the body" refers to conventional death. It doesn't refer to instant death of experiences.

Comment: Evidence? Thanks

Comment: The excerpt from [your own question here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/how-does-ajita-kesakambali-compare-to-the-buddha) has a reference which is clearly describing about conventional death :)

Comment: Sankha kulanthantille so the break up of the body is when the body is cremated rather than when you die?

Comment: @TheDBSGuy it refers to death.

Comment: I don’t know if this is truth but when people die do their mind made body come out of their body and wander around till their body is cremated or destroyed?

Comment: @TheDBSGuy when the person is dead, the body cannot support the mental stream anymore. So it doesn't matter if the body is cremated or not. It is just going to rot if it is not cremated.

Comment: There are beliefs in some Buddhist countries that when a person die their “soul” come out of the body and that it look just like the physical body and wander around. For me, this doesn’t make sense because as long as there is a body invisible of visible the five aggregates are present therefore there is no soul.

Comment: There is no such thing called the soul according to Buddhism. It could be a Peta or a Gandhabba life.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 things that defines your lifespan. Body heat, Life span (Ayusha) and Consiousness. All 3 things needs to come to an end to have your body break apart as mentioned in your question. The heat of the body should fade away, the life span should come to an end and the consiousness leaves the body.

That is why when Arahants are in Nirodha Samapatti which means they are not breathing, literally, they don't die. Because those 3 factors are still there.

That's what you mean by "at the break of the body".

Answer (score -5):

My answer:

The word 'kaya' means 'group' or 'collection'.

The word 'death' or 'marana' means the death of 'a being' ('satta'), which is a 'self-view', as stated in SN 23.2, SN 5.10 and SN 12.2.

For example, if a person gets drunk on alcohol, the body (*rupa*) & mind (*nama*) are made up of a certain & specific collection of aggregates & elements, such as alcohol in the blood & happy feelings & uninhibited thoughts. The drunk person or aggregates identifies with being drunk & dances & sings: "I am so happy. I love alcohol".

But when the alcohol wears off; this is the ending of the 'kaya' ('body'). This is 'death' of that state of 'being' or 'identity'.

The next day, the person or aggregates have a very bad headache from drinking alcohol and regret they drank alcohol. Here, a new 'being' ('satta' - illusion of self) takes birth in hell (suffering) because of the kamma of drinking alcohol.

Therefore, "break-up of the body after death" means the break-up of one collection of aggregates & the arising of another collection of aggregates, which also results in the death of a self-identity and birth of a new self-identity.

The is why the suttas say: "*In laying down one body & taking up another body is blameworthy*".

This is a knowable visible here & now and non-materialistic discernment.